# Position of words

Tags: grammar

```
We show now that this algorithm can do X.
We now show that this algorithm can do X.
Next we show that this algorithm can do X.
Now we show that this algorithm can do X.
```

What is better english, and are there general rules to this kind of objects in the sentence?

Comment: They are all written in grammatical, fluent English. It is just a matter of preference and context. (**Next** would follow something)

Comment: and how do you know what is correct in the context?

Comment: I think all of them presume there was a previous step. Also, many would consider the word "that" is superfluous.